Conjugation of Matrices over Rational Functions
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $k(t)$ the field of rational functions over $k$. For a matrix $A(t) \in k(t)^{n\times n}$ suppose that there is a matrix $B \in k^{n\times n}$ with the following property: For infinitely many $\lambda \in k$ there is an invertible matrix $C_\lambda\in k^{n\times n}$ with $C_\lambda A(\lambda) C_\lambda^{-1} = B$. In that case, can we find an invertible matrix $C(t) \in k(t)^{n\times n}$ such that $C(t) A(t) C(t)^{-1} = B$?

In what context did you come across this question?

Yes this is always possible:
First remember that the charecteristic polynomial of a matrix is invariant under base change of our vector space. So we get that for each $\lambda$, where we have the equality $C_{\lambda}A(\lambda)C_{\lambda}^{-1}=B$ we have that $\chi_{A(\lambda)}(x)=\chi_B(x) = b_n x^n+...+b_0 \in k[x]$.
On the other hand we can calculate $\chi_{A(t)}(x) = \frac{f_n(t)}{g_n(t)}x^n+...+\frac{f_0(t)}{g_0(t)}\in k(t)[x]$ and we get an equality if we set $t=\lambda$ for infinitely many lambdas. So if we compare coefficients of those polynomials in $x$ we get that the coefficients $\frac{f_i(t)}{g_i(t)}$ of $\chi_{A(t)}(x)$, which are rational functions equal some $b_i$ for infinetly many $t$ (those from the assumtpion). Therefore, we get $\frac{f_i(t)}{g_i(t)}\in k$ and thereby $\chi_{A(t)}(x) \in k[x]$.
Now $k$ is algebraically closed so the characteristic polynomials (which both lie in $k[x]$) split into linear factors and they have the same $k$-valued eigenvalues with same algebraic multiplicity and we can write them both as their Jordan form with same entries on the diagonal. We need to check that the Jordan blocks agree. But as the only differences of the Jordan blocks lie in the placement of ones above the diagonal, which are constant in $t$, it is enough to show this for one evaluation of $t=\lambda$, but we have infinitely many such $\lambda$ so the Jordan blocks have to agree (Jordan forms of similar matrices are the same). So we see that both $A(t)$ and $B$ have the same Jordan form and as similarity is transitive they are similar.
